# What program/s or application can compile my Java Server Code, Android Client Code and Asynctask code?

Tags: java, compilation

Assuming that I have my Java server code, Android client code and asynctask code, what program or application can compile / write my codes?

What program can run my code in Java Server, Android Client, and Asynctask? I found codes on google but I don't know where to paste it. I'm missing the program/application. What is / are the suitable application(s) that can do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by your `ASyncTask` code as this would be part of the android code.

Anyway, your android code can be run from Eclipse but you would need the Android SDK and ADT plugin for eclipse. Details of which can be found [here](http://developer.android.com). There are other IDEs but this is probably the most used and if you are beginner at android Google has all the documentation about eclipse which will make things easier.

As for your java server, this can be run in Eclipse, but there are lots of other browsers that can be used, Netbeans is another example.